# Validate password against regular expression?

Tags: password, keyboard-layout, authentication

Is it possible to somehow set a regular expression that would validate a user's password? So that if the regexp is set to: `^qwerty|йцуке$` than both `qwerty` and `йцуке` will be valid passwords.

I want this because I frequently change keyboard layouts and it is annoying when your password does not match due to wrong layout. I would love it if the same sequence of keys in both layouts would result in password being accepted and figured that could be solved by setting a regexp to some sort of validation policy. Feel free to suggest a better approach to this problem.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: That won't solve the problem, because as it is PAM doesn't accept regular expressions as it is.

Comment: This question on SU might be of interest to you: [“Allowing multiple passwords attached to one account (Linux)”](https://superuser.com/q/152412/238583)

Comment: Unix does not store passwords, just hashes (fortunately). So your best bet is to try to convince PAM to do it (I'm thinking about having a second passwd/shadow file pairs with the second password --- but I never tried it). Useful links: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/User-Authentication-HOWTO/x115.html and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps